# GooglePlay services integration with froyo fails in gradle

Tags: android

I am on Android Studio and I have followed the instructions [on Google here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#play).

I have downloaded via the SDK Manager the google repository, google play services for froyo and not for froyo.

My gradle

```
// this works
// compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'
// this doesn't
// compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'
```

(I uncomment one or the other, not both at the same time)

My manifest

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

iirc, Google doesn't actually provide an aar for froyo play services. I think you have to manually import ANDROID_SDK\extras\google\google_play_services_froyo\libproject\google-play-ser‌​vices_lib from your SDK directory as a module, then compile that module as a dependency in gradle.

The link you referenced that you were following mentions nothing about froyo or gradle, are you sure you're following the right tutorial? This seems to indicate my answer above if correct: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is from Nov 2013 to hardcode the gms version in the manifest

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61675

Comment: I did that ('3265130' for me) but the problem is in <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity>, they don't recognize it

Comment: And I added the jar to my project as @pandanomic suggested

Answer (score 0):

"com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" does not exist in version 3.2.65 (Froyo) of Google Play Services. Google seems to have stopped updating the library for google_play_services_froyo.

a[image: class names in gms package]

you will need to use google_play_services (current version is 4.3.23) to use AdView and AdRequest, but that version requires a minsdk of 9 (Gingerbread).

I am facing the same problem as you, and I have a small percentage of active users still using Froyo (mostly in third world countries). For now I intend to split my apps to different flavors- one of which will use the Admob standalone SDK until they stop serving ads (and it'll remain ad free for my Froyo users).